# Testbench in VHDL

Tags: testing, vhdl, modelsim

I have designed an entity multiply and an architecture which implements this entity, but I don't know how to write a testbench for that. In other words: how can I pass values to my architecture?
I'm not sure if this codes is right at all, but I can't test it without passing values to it.

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity multiply is
port (
    in_A : in std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    in_B : in std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    out_Q : out std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end multiply;

architecture multiply_arch of multiply is
signal p0 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal p1 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal p2 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal p3 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal p4 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal p5 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal p6 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal p7 : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
p0 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(0)) and in_B;
p1 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(1)) and in_B;
p2 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(2)) and in_B;
p3 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(3)) and in_B; 
p4 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(4)) and in_B;
p5 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(5)) and in_B;
p6 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(6)) and in_B; 
p7 <= (7 downto 0 => in_A(7)) and in_B;

out_Q(15 downto 1) <= std_ulogic_vector((unsigned(p0) + unsigned(p1&"0") + unsigned(p2&"00") + unsigned(p3&"000") + unsigned(p4&"0000") + unsigned(p5&"00000") + unsigned(p6&"000000") + unsigned(p7&"0000000")));
end architecture multiply_arch;
```

Comment: -1 Clearly homework. Clearly has not read their first chapter on VHDL coding, or which ever chapter deals with entity instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component definition and then instantiate that component in another file.  This file will be your test bench file.

The test bench file will need to have the `component` which looks like this:

```
component multiply is
port (
    in_A : in std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    in_B : in std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    out_Q : out std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end component multiply;
```

Then below the `begin` statement for your `architecture` you need the component instantiation which will look something like this:

```
multiply_inst : multiply
port map (
    in_A  => test_A,
    in_B  => test_B,
    out_Q => test_out
);
```

You will need to drive signals test_A and test_B from your testbench, and look at the result of signal test_out to see if your multiply module is performing as expected.

For a complete example of this see: how to [create a testbench in VHDL](http://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-your-first-vhdl-program-part2.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `multiply` entity has few input bits (only 16 `std_logic`) and there is no
clock or state in the module, so an exhaustive test bench that tries all 0/1
combinations of the inputs can be created.  This test bench can include a
"reference" model, which in the case of multiply operation simply is a `*`.

A suggestion for such an test bench is included below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity multiply_tb is
end entity;


library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture sim of multiply_tb is

  signal dut_in_a  : std_ulogic_vector( 7 downto 0);
  signal dut_in_b  : std_ulogic_vector( 7 downto 0);
  signal dut_out_q : std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);

  signal dut_ok : boolean;

begin

  -- Device Under Test (DUT)
  multiply_e : entity work.multiply
    port map(
        in_A => dut_in_a,
        in_B => dut_in_b,
        out_Q => dut_out_q);

  -- Result generation
  dut_ok <= to_integer(unsigned(dut_in_a)) * to_integer(unsigned(dut_in_b)) =
            to_integer(unsigned(dut_out_q(15 downto 1)));

  -- Stimuli generation and result test
  process is
    variable in_a_v  : natural;
    variable in_b_v  : natural;
    variable out_q_v : natural;
  begin
    for in_a_v in 0 to 255 loop
      for in_b_v in 0 to 255 loop
        dut_in_a <= std_ulogic_vector(to_unsigned(in_a_v, dut_in_a'length));
        dut_in_b <= std_ulogic_vector(to_unsigned(in_b_v, dut_in_b'length));
        wait for 5 ns;
        assert dut_ok report "DUT failed" severity ERROR;
        wait for 5 ns;
      end loop;
    end loop;
    wait;  -- End of simulation
  end process;

end architecture;
```

Note that it looks like there is some bug in the `multiply` entity, since bit 0
of `out_Q` is not driven, and the upper bits does not create proper multiply
result.  When the issue is fixed, then the result generation (reference model)
should be updated as appropriate.

Comment: Think the test bench shows a pretty useful concept for verifying that kind of module, so maybe others may also benefit from the scheme.